# Acquire patents data from BigQuery by application

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to collect data by application_number like this.

```
SELECT p.application_number AS app, COUNT(c.publication_number) AS Citations 
     FROM 'patents-public-data.patents.publications' AS p, UNNEST(citation) AS c 
     WHERE p.application_number IN ('CN201510747352'
         ) 
     GROUP BY p.application_number
```

But it can't work. The url is the patent page. Who can do me a favor?
[patent_application_number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKxny.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  p.application_number AS app, 
  SUM((SELECT COUNT(publication_number) FROM UNNEST(citation))) AS Citations 
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS p
WHERE p.application_number IN ('CN-201510747352-A') 
GROUP BY p.application_number
```

with result

```
Row app                 Citations    
1   CN-201510747352-A   14
```

Please note: your original query will work if you will use `CN-201510747352-A` instead of `CN201510747352` as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT p.application_number AS app, COUNT(c.publication_number) AS Citations 
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS p, 
UNNEST(citation) AS c 
WHERE p.application_number IN ('CN-201510747352-A') 
GROUP BY p.application_number
```

but still - I recommend  you using the query I provided - the reason is  - if given application has no citation at all - such application will not be returned in output whereas recommended query will return count = 0

for example  - if you will comment out WHERE clause in both queries - first will return 76,073,734; while second will return  29,489,639 apps.

It might be not that important in this particular use case  - but good to have in mind for your next queries

> Another question is the number queried is 14 which is not the same as 7 in original website. Is there any mistakes in it?

7 is correct answer - see below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  p.application_number AS app, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.publication_number) Citations 
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS p,
UNNEST(citation) c
WHERE p.application_number IN ('CN-201510747352-A') 
GROUP BY p.application_number
```

with result

```
Row app                 Citations    
1   CN-201510747352-A   7
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I want to realize the purpose of counting the forward citations, so I change the query like this                                                                                          SELECT c.application_number AS app, COUNT(p.publication_number) AS CitedBy 
     FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS p, UNNEST(citation) AS c 
     WHERE c.application_number IN  ('CN-201510747352-A') 
GROUP BY c.application_number    , It still can not work.

Comment: Another question is the number queried is 14 which is not the same as 7 in original website. Is there any mistakes in it?

Comment: How can I count the number of forward citation ,not the backward?

Comment: this is your new question  - right? the one you just posted - correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm desperate for the answer. I also want to asked  how can I realize my purpose there are ten of thousands of numbers like CN201510747352 in a Excel document.

Comment: If the application number is like PCT/CN2009/071410, how can I edit it?https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2010121423A1/ja

Comment: you should use - `WHERE application_number LIKE 'CN-2009071410%'`; so as you can see `PCT/` is to be omit as well as `/` between numbers - this was the best i was able to 'reverse engineer' - If you have more question(s) - 1. check yours already posted and accept/vote where appropriate and then 2. post your new question - i will not be able to keep answering your in-comments followups as it becomes too messy - but will be glad to answer new posted questions